# EF6 app.config complete configuration option reference

Tags: .net, entity-framework, app-config

I'm trying to find a complete guide to learn the configuration section  inside the app.config.

I currently have these sections in my app.config:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

and

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

And I can't find the specifications for what can I write in .
I'm using EF 6.2 so I wonder also if the first statement is about version 6.0.
This code works, but I have no idea where to start to "touch" it.

If you have a reference for the various parameters and the specifications for the first statement would really be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't want to touch these parts at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I updated my EF library to 6.2 so I'd like to understand if any of the information there is old. And for future upgrade of course.

Comment: You probably used NuGet to upgrade EF. NuGet will revise these configuration parts as well, when necessary, so you really don't need to edit them. Note that there's a difference between assembly version and file version (6.0.0.0 and 6.2.61023.0, respectively).

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to see the reference for this know-how. any link?